# Good ways to setup development environment on Mac for ActionScript

Tags: macos, actionscript

There is a very close question here: [actionscript development on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503998/actionscript-development-on-mac). Howerver, the answers are two years ago. There are comments under the question asking for updates but got no response. So I am here to ask.

What are some good ways to setup ActionScript development environment on MAC? If Adobe CreativeSuite is installed, that should give you a complete dev environment? If so, why people are still asking about IDE?

I personally prefer Vim + command line tools. I found that Flex SDK http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html might be able to serve for this purpose. However, not sure whether it will have some compatibility problem. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a MAC user but I think the accepted answer in the question you link to probably still stands; namely if you want to do serious ActionScript development on a MAC you should be considering either [FlashBuilder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html) or [FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/product/).

The answer to your second question will depend on the version of CreativeSuite you have installed. If you have the [master collection](http://www.adobe.com/products/creativesuite/mastercollection.html), which appears to include FlashBuilder 4.6 Premium, you're in luck. Otherwise not as the Flash IDE (ironically) is pretty dreadful for writing ActionScript.